# Get request query parameters aren't applying

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I'm trying to use query parameters in a get request in Express, but there are no parameters in the request body

On the frontend

```
query () {
    if (window.location.href === 'http://localhost:3000/profile') {
        window.location.href = `?contributer=${localStorage.getItem('username')}`;
    }
    fetch('http://localhost:3002/get-user-recipes')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        this.setState({
            apiResponse: data
        });
    });
}
```

and on the backend

```
app.get('/get-user-recipes', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query); // returns {}
});
```

Comment: first of all your localStorage.getItem parameter is invalid, then you're not sending any data to the backend, hence your req.query is an empty object.

Comment: @Adnomination wouldn't that mean req.query = { contributer: undefined }

Comment: yes your'e right. But that is not happening which means that fetch is not sending the query object. And I am not sure why, as by looking at your code everything seems fine apart from the contributer.

Comment: comment out the if statement and check if req.query returns http://localhost:3000/profile

Comment: still returns the same {}

Answer (score 2):

Ok I figured it out. The parameters need to go in the express path, so the correct code is
fetch(`http://localhost:3002/get-user-recipes?contributer=${localStorage.getItem('username')}`)

Comment: Great, that you could figure it out 

Answer (score 0):

Query Params are usually at the end of a url and are initiated with a `?`

Example:

// On the frontend
Making a get request to say :

```
http://localhost:3002/get-user-recipes?one=1&two=2
```

The query Params here are *one* with value of '1' and two with a value of '2'

// On the backend

```
app.get('/get-user-recipes', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.query); // would return { one: '1', two: ,'2' }
});
```